# Phalcon Volt, how to print translation with a variable

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm using Phalcon with Volt for my multilanguage application.

I've setup a translation file which contains the following variables:

```
'numbervalidation-field' => '%field% is a number',
'Teams' => 'Teams',
```

And this is how I print 'Teams is a number' correctly

```
<?php echo $t->_("numbervalidation-field", array("field" => $t->_('Teams'))); ?>
```

I just want to be able to print the same using volt, I've tried several things but nothing works, this was my latest attempt:

```
{{t['numbervalidation-field', ['field': t['Teams']]]}}
```

Help please, I couldn't find how to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `_()` function in Volt as well? Like `{{ t_('number....') }}`.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov, shouldn't it be `{{ t._('number') }}`? (a missing `.`)

Comment: @Timothy it should! Thanks :)

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov, quickly! Edit it, before anyone notices!

Comment: @Timothy Can't, time for edits ran out. He will read your comment, no worries ;)

Comment: Thanks for your effort @NikolayMihaylov and Timothy but it didn't work. I get 'Macro 't_' does not exist'. BTW this works properly {{t['Teams']}}

Comment: Please check out my answer. I'm pretty sure that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to assign your `$t` variable, which is the translating object, to `$this->view->t` in your view's controller.

Open your controller file, find an appropriate action and add

```
$this->view->t = $t;
```

somewhere where you can use $t to translate your strings. It's a good idea to put it in a base controller so you can use it in every view.

Then you're free to use translation with `{{ t._('SOMETHING') }}`. You can also add an array with fields to replace as a second parameter in your volt translating function like this:

```
{{ t._('CODE',[parameters]) }}
```

where `[parameters]` is an array that has replacements for string fields with values by keys.

Comment: OP is asking how to use the translator **with variables**. Your example is just a normal translation. If possible, extend your example with the use of translation variables!

Comment: @Timothy Sure, will do soon

Comment: Thanks @Luke, looking forward to seeing it with variables

Comment: Hi @Luke, when we say variables, we mean one of the parameters is a translation variable, as you can see in the question I've tried {{t['numbervalidation-field', ['field': t['Teams']]]}} but it doesn't work, so how can I put a variable as parameter? Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter for ease of use, assuming your Translation service is `$di->t`, that would read:

```
$volt->getCompiler()->addFilter('trans', function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
    return sprintf('$this->t->query(%s)', $resolvedArgs);
});
```

Then, in the volt template, you can do:

```
{{ 'name'|trans }}
```

In your case, you'll have two translations, so it could read:

```
{{ 'numbervalidation-field'|trans({'field': ('Teams'|trans)}) }}
```